# Moodle - where are URLs/links stored in database?

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm exporting an old release 1.9.2 and importing to 3.0.2. 
Each module has dozens of videos that I play via an URL/link, which points to my own .PHP program on the site (and that wraps a Camtasia video).

I found that in 3.0.2, the link opens on a separate page, unless I edit each link by going to "Appearance", then "Display" and setting it to "Embed".

So I would like to write a mySQL update script to automatically set this flag for all such links (I will add a where clause to my script name).

I checked database in PHP/MyAdmin, and didn't see any likely table names.

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to use the admin tools to update everything, go to your moodle installation's main URL.

Then go to the site administration. After /admin in the url, add /tool/replace and go there.

You can there enter what you want to find in the db, and replace it with another value. Just be carefull with this tool and **make a backup** before you begin.